# Problem with Silverlight binding

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, binding, listbox

I have the following XAML:

```
 ...
 <ListBox Name ="RoomsListBox" Height="100"
 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,41,0,0"
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"></ListBox>
 ...
```

And the following C#-code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     RoomsListBox.ItemsSource = new[] { new { Name = "First1" },
       new { Name = "First2" } };
     RoomsListBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
}
```

The problem is that my ListBox have items but they are empty. Why I don't see "First1" and "First2" instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here isn't with the bindings nor the ItemTemplate nor the change notification. It's the *Anonymous Type* you're using that's causing it. try using a class or struct for your items

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    RoomsListBox.ItemsSource = new[] { 
                                        new Item { Name = "First1" },
                                        new Item { Name = "First2" }};
    RoomsListBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
}
```

your xaml stays the same, or you can define a DataTemplate for the ListBox items if you want. Note that you can't set both the `ItemTemplate` and `DisplayMemberPath` at the same time (one has to be null). Also, make sure that the class representing your items has to be public.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It really helped. Thank you. I already used a separate class, but the problem remained. It was because anonymous class and my newly created class were private instead of being public. I am just wondering why there is no warning or exception about it?

Comment: the problem here is that the data binding mechanism doesn't have access to your class, so it knows nothing about it (nor how to bind to it)! lack of warnings, exceptions and most importantly "debugging" is an issue with DataBinding in general! that's going to change with Silverlight 5 which is going to introduce "DataBinding Debugging", and that's pretty COOOL :)

Comment: Thanks for explanations and for good news concerning Silverlight 5 :)

Comment: there's actually a lot of good stuff coming out with Silverlight 5, you can find more about that watching [Scott Guthrie's Keynote for the Silverlight FireStarter](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Silverlight-Firestarter/Silverlight-Firestarter-2010-Keynote-with-Scott-Guthrie)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `DisplayMemberPath` property on your ListBox to `Name`.

Moving forward you might want to consider creating a `DataTemplate` for your items to have more control:

```
<ListBox x:Name ="RoomsListBox" Height="100"
 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,41,0,0"
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
               </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

See this tutorial for more info: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-5-using-the-listbox-and-databinding-to-display-list-data.aspx

Comment: Sorry, missed that, was looking for it in xaml. Added an example for DataTemplate you can use as is, I think it's a better solution anyway!

Comment: I changed my XAML. But I still have a list with an empty items. And I don't understand how it can be possible. A Default ToString() method never returns empty strings.

Comment: More of that. I don't have any TextBlock in the list either.

Comment: Strange... just try removing things until you found where is it going wrong. So what happens if you put in the items hardcoded in XAML, with no datatemplate or displaymemberpath, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought..

Have you tried settings the DisplayMemberPath property in XAML? There might be an issue with the order of calls.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer that you define your binding in your xaml and for example in your Code-Behind you define a property for the items of your listbox.

Example: (xaml)

```
<ListBox Name ="RoomsListBox" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" 
         Height="100" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         Margin="12,41,0,0" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top" 
         Width="120" />
```

Example: (C# in your code-behind)

```
//...
private ObservableCollection<string> _myItems;

public ObservableCollection<String> MyItems 
{
    get 
    {
        return _myItems ?? (_myItems = new ObservableCollection<string> { "FirstItem", "SecondItem"});
    }
    set
    {
        _myItems = value;
    }
}
```

Like ChrisF said you could use the INotifiyPropertyChanged Interface, there you would raise the PropertyChanged event in the setter of your property.

See --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

Comment: I've deleted my answer as, on reflection (via a comment), I don't think it's relevant in this case. Unless the OP rewrites his code along these lines of course.